# From Polymer3 to lit-element and material components: replacement for paper-tabs and iron-pages

Tags: polymer, lit-element

I am porting a Polymer 3 app to lit-element stepwise and also want to replace the paper and iron elements by material web components. I very often am using the combination of `paper-tabs` and `iron-pages` to show property pages/dialogs.

What would be the replacement for `paper-tabs`/`iron-pages` in the material web components world?

I have found `mwc-tab-bar` but there is no example for actually displaying contents according to the selected tab.

Has anyone an example for how to build what sometimes is called a page-control (tabs plus contents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options: (I would prefer 1 & 3)

1. You could just create a condition to render and eventually lazy load a certain page.
2. Use something like [lion-steps](https://lion-web-components.netlify.com/?path=/story/navigation-steps--default-story) (they also provide tabs)
3. Use a router like [simple-wc-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-wc-router)

```js
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      page: String,
    }
  }

  get _oneTemplate() {
    return html`Page one`;
  }

  get _twoTemplate() {
    return html`Page two`;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.page = 'one';
    setTimeout(() => (this.page = 'two'), 5000);
  }
  render() {
    return this.page === 'one' ? this._oneTemplate : this._twoTemplate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that are enough options to solve my current task. I was just wondering why the Google team implements tabs but does not show a single example on how to actually show content (probably it's assumed to be too trivial ;-)) Also I was wondering why the Polymer team felt the need to make a special component for it (iron-pages) but the new team does not so and leaves it to us.

Comment: I think iron-pages were very much needed in the old Polymer 2/3 way of rendering everything as HTML tags. With lit & HTML literals we do far more things in javascript which makes stuff easier - esp. conditional rendering. No need for iron-pages or a substitution imo.

I think the role of tabs is to render the tabs and to fire an event or set a property if the active tab changes. What you do with that property change is your thing :)